# php spam filter not working with wildcards (asterisks)

Tags: php, wildcard, spam

Got a problem with spammers and I created a function to filter out the spam.
However, if a spammer is using the word `*S*P*A*M*` (with asterisks between), I somehow can't filter it out and when I try to add it like this to the banned words list, strangely every "`M`" is banned now.

```
    function censor_spam($field_value) {
    global $setting;
    $spam = FALSE;
    $censored_array = explode(",", trim($setting['setting_banned_words']));
    foreach ($censored_array as $key => $value) {
        $trimvalue = trim($value);
        if (strpos($field_value, $trimvalue) !== false) {
            $spam = TRUE;
        }
    }
    return $spam;
}
```

Are the asterisks somehow irritating this anti-spam function?

Any ideas what I need to change in my function to fix?

Comment: `str_replace('*', '', $field_value);` - Then run your check. However, a 'bad words' list is fairly flawed.

Comment: @MikeB That's a solution I guess, but with some negative side effects, nobody could post any wildcard character anymore at all, it would be removed.

Comment: That's exactly the problem with a 'bad words' solution - it's flimsy. And you wouldn't leave it out of their original message.. just when you're scanning it for bad words.